# Remove :id from Ecto.Changeset based off of struct with an id

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have a simple operation that retrieves a document from the DB, modifies a value, and then attempts to re-insert it as a new document. In other words, I want to duplicate a document that already exists in the database. Unsurprisingly, this operation fails the unique primary key constraint:

```
Ecto.ConstraintError:

constraint error when attempting to insert struct:
  * unique: docs_pkey
```

Trying to clear the `id` from the changeset using `put_change(doc, :id, null)` yields the following error:

```
ERROR (not_null_violation): null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

I imagine what I need to do instead is remove `id` field from the changeset entirely, but I couldn't find any conventional way of doing that in the [changeset documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html).

---

It's easy enough to strip the `id` off of the struct using something like `Map.put(doc, :id, nil)`, but for my specific application it would be better if I could remove the `id` from the changeset.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar using code like this for a schema called `Upload`, where upload is the item from the database that I want to copy. Does this help you?

```
changeset =
    upload
    |> Map.put(:id, nil)
    |> Upload.changeset(new_params)
    |> Repo.insert
```

Comment: This certainly works (I actually included this solution as part of my question if you take a look at the note at the bottom), but I want to be able to remove the `id` from the changeset.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is appropriate, here is few examples to construct duplicate changeset (for module `Myapp.Doc`) with method that takes changeset as argument (not just struct)

```
def duplicate_changeset(changeset) do
  changeset.data
  |> Map.delete(:id)
  |> changeset
end

def duplicate_changeset(changeset) do
  changeset
  |> Map.put(:data, Map.delete(changeset.data, :id))
end

def duplicate_changeset(changeset) do
  %{changeset | data: Map.delete(changeset.data, :id)}
end
```

It still deletes key `:id` but from `changeset.data`

Here is the test:

```
test "duplicate persisted changeset" do
  changeset = %Doc{name: "some content", body: "some content"}
  |> Repo.insert!
  |> Doc.changeset

  duplicate_changeset = Doc.duplicate_changeset(changeset)
  assert duplicate_changeset.valid?
  Repo.insert! duplicate_changeset
  assert length(Repo.all(Doc)) == 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn’t [`Ecto.Changeset#delete_change/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#delete_change/2) suffice?

```
changeset = ...
changeset
  |> Ecto.Changeset.delete_change(:id)
  |> Repo.insert!
```

Comment: This doesn't work - it removes `:id` only from recent change, not from the data. I have tested and got error: `(Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct: * unique: docs_pkey`

Comment: @OleksandrAvoyants it depends on how this `changeset` was built and I could not parse this info from OP. That’s why I used “wouldn’t”.

Comment: I think it will not work under any circumstances. Unless for new records (not persisted) if field `:id` is available to be set manually in `cast`.